# Anybody know of a way to disable keybindings in Thunderbird 68?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I'm in the process of migrating my work Mac from Mojave on its internal HDD to Catalina on a USB3.1 SSD.

I've just learned that Dorando Keyconfig don't bloody work on T-Bird 68 (sounds like a Ford!)

When I put Dorando Keyconfig on my T-Bird 60, I'd long-since lost count of the number of times I'd been caught by the "unmodified-key" shortcut bindings (e.g., 0-9 for tagging, A for archive, R for mark thread as read, J for mark as junk, &c.) with unintended consequences. (By rights, key-bindings ought to be easily modifiable without *any* extension!)

Does anybody here know of a way to disable the "unmodified-key" bindings in T-Bird 68 and later?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible at the moment, no extension can alter them. After all, Thunderbird's developers know which shortcuts are useful for you much more than you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just installed [tbkeys-lite](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/reviews/), which seems to do the job.  The "Unset singles" button doesn't seem to override already set keybindings, but it suffices to add

```
{
    "0": "unset",
    "1": "unset",
    "2": "unset",
    "3": "unset",
    "4": "unset",
    "5": "unset",
    "6": "unset",
    "7": "unset",
    "8": "unset",
    "9": "unset",
    "j": "unset",
    "k": "unset",
    "o": "unset",
    "f": "unset",
    "#": "unset",
    "r": "unset",
    "a": "unset",
    "x": "unset",
    "c": "unset",
    "u": "unset",
    "b": "unset",
    "m": "unset",
    "p": "unset",
    "s": "unset",
    "t": "unset",
    "w": "unset",
    "]": "unset",
    "[": "unset"
}
```

in the "Main key bindings" field to disable them.

Comment: I took a look at tbkeys-lite, only hours ago, on my *new* new work Mac, and couldn't figure it out. Then I saw your reply to a question I'd completely forgotten I'd even asked, put tbkeys-lite on, with your bindings, and it worked perfectly. Belated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the thunderbird keyboard shorcuts, go to the menu Tools - settings - general - config editor (at the end of the page) -  look for, type or past the following :

accessibility.browsewithcaret_shortcut.enabled

clic it to put it to : false instead of true

This command disables all thunderbird keyboard shortcuts at once. To get them back, change false to true.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).